# How can I reliably change SelectedItem on WP7 ListBox without firing Tap?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a ListBox in my WP7 App, which has an ItemTemplate for it's items.

The template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TapCountryItemTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="12,6,12,6" Tap="OnTapped">
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" /> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" 
             FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's an image of the result:

[image: Selection Screenshot]

If you slowly press on the right hand side of the list items, (so it's not a tap) the selection in the list box is changed when you lift your finger.

If however, you perform the same action on the yellow area, you don't get a change of selection, though the item tilts.

You can see the behaviour in action (without the yellow) in our app here:
http://www.wieser-software.com/m/travel

Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, removing the tap handler in the template above causes the selection to work as expected...

So how can adding a Tap Handler that doesn't get called make the selection of the list behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two competing things going on here.

1. You want to indicate an item in the list as being distinct from the others at a moment in time. That is, it is "selected". When an item is selected you are allowing the default behaviour of the foreground color being changed to the accent color to indicate this.
2. You want to allow the user to tap on an item to trigger navigation to another page, related to the item tapped.

From looking at your app, it appears that you're using the selected state to indicate the item (country) that was selected last. I would question the value of this (do people not remember what they were just looking at) but that is your choice.

So, what's actually going on here?

- When you touch the TextBlock but don't trigger the Tap event in the outer control the touch event is lost and does not bubble up to the ListBoxItem to trigger the selected state change.
- When you do trigger the Tap event the touch is also bubbled up to the ListBoxItem and the selected state is changed.
- Because the width of your grid is only as wide as it's contents (the TextBlock) it is possible to touch the ListBoxItem outside of the Grid and trigger the changing of the selected item. You do get the tilt here because that is set on the ListBoxItem, not the Grid.

You could probably avoid the unintended behaviour (of selection changing when not triggering a tap event) by making sure the Grid takes up the full space (width) occupied by the ListBoxItem. The simplest way to do this would be to set the width of the Grid.

However.
If it was me and I wanted a way to indicate the last viewed item, I wouldn't rely on the selection state of the items in the ListBox being kept in sync correctly (including across tombstoning) but would add a property to the underlying viewmodel which I would use to manually track this by changing it only when a tap event and navigation is triggered. The color of the most-recently-selected-item could then be set in code (or via a converter on a binding). Doing it this way would allow complete control over what the UI looks like at any point.

Comment: Thanks Matt,
I do actually have the SelectedItem in the view model, but was assuming that I could do it by having the SelectedItem updated by the list itself.

The behaviour of non-tap selecting the item was what I wanted (as I didn't want to code up a context menu, and instead use the buttons to handle deletion etc.)

I was a little surprised to find that Hold in the same area also prevent selection of the ListBox.

Where did you find the info about bubbling behaviour?

Comment: I know Silverlight has event bubbling and made the conclusion based on what I was observing in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick question: why handle Grid Tap and not ListBox SelectionChanged ?

As far as I can see, SelectionChanged is causing selection and the Tap is causing the navigation to desired details page

if you want to use Tap and not SelectionChanged set TextBlock to HorizontalAlignment to Stretch so Grid occupies full width

Comment: I think selection changed only fires if it actually changed, so I'm handling tap to fire off the navigation.

But, I want to allow the user to change the selection too.  Hence the question about how to select without the tap.

Comment: well in that case you want explicit option for user to select navigation.. ie a button in app bar etc which says go  to details page

Answer (score 0):

Based on Matt's suggestions, here's how I achieved what I wanted:

1. A tap event navigates to the page the user suggests
2. Not tapping still selects the item, so if you do it slowly, or swipe to the right, I select the item.

First, I had to get my grid to extend.  Matt suggested setting a width, but I used this trick before in Silverlight:

```
<Style x:Name="Stretchy" TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

and set my ListBox up accordingly:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Stretchy}" .../>
```

Finally, in my DataTemplate (above) I added a handler for

```
MouseLeftButtonUp="ButtonUp"
```

and implemented it in code behind (but you could do it with a behaviour) like this:

```
private void ButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // set the selected item to the data context, which forces the listbox to highlight correctly
    App.VM.SelectedCountry = ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext) as CountryData;
}
```

Note that handling the ButtonUp event can be difficult depending on the other xaml in the control.  To solve this, I overlaid the entire control in a different project with a Rectangle that has an opacity of 0.01, and attached the event to the rectangle instead of the grid.